# Can't get reproducible vector using set.seed

Tags: r, random, random-seed

I'm taking a self-study introductory class in R, and the question is:

> Use the `grep()` function to find the indices of the letter "x" and
> find the frequency of "a" from the randomletters vector.

The vector is already given:

```
set.seed(10)
randomletters <- letters[sample(1:26, 100, replace = T)]
```

I run the code `grep("x",randomletters)` and I get 11, 18, 41, and 65 for the indices. The answers that I got are not in the list of answers to choose from.

[image: question]

I run the code `grep("a",randomletters)` and I get 4 as the frequency and it is the wrong answer.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is something wrong with the question (item). A) `"a"`, B) `"n" "u"`, C) `"l" "o" "e" "j" "w" "n"`, D) `"p" "r" "r" "j"` and E) `"h" "u" "r" "x" "u"`.

Comment: Your subject line is incorrect, if you look at the output it is being reproduced consistently. QED, the quiz question itself is erroneous.

Answer (score 8):

You have the correct answer in both cases.

The answer key in your image includes 34 for the indices instead of the 4 values you saw. That probably indicates that it was produced using the buggy version of the `sample()` function that was fixed in early 2019.  You can use that version by running

```
RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding")
```

I don't recommend doing this for any reason except reproducing obsolete results.

Once you're done checking answers against that answer key, you can return it to normal using

```
RNGkind(sample.kind = "default")
```